# Proof $\sqrt{x}$ is continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, continuity

I proved, that $\sqrt{x}$ is continuous, can somebody check, did I make it correct?
I need help only with case $y=0$. I know that $\delta=\epsilon^2$ will work, but will my $\epsilon$ work?

$\textbf{Proof:}$ Let $\delta>0$ and $|x-y|=|x-0|=|x|<\delta$. Then take $\delta:=...$
$|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|=|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{0}|=|\sqrt{x}|=\Big \lvert\frac{x}{\sqrt{x}} \Big \rvert<\Big \lvert\frac{\delta}{\sqrt{x}} \Big \rvert<\delta=\epsilon.$

So we can take $\delta:=\epsilon$. Does it work?

$\textbf{Edit}$: I think, I unterstood, it will not work, because $\Big \lvert\frac{\delta}{\sqrt{x}} \Big \rvert<\delta$ is not always true. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, your last statement showcases the problem. Note that that inequality holds for the vast majority of the (positive) real axis though, and you can use a different epsilon for the small part where it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in saying that $|\frac{\delta}{\sqrt{x}}|<\delta$ is not true if $|\sqrt{x}|\leq 1$.

More generally if you want to take $\delta = \epsilon$, realise that if $\epsilon<1$, the we have $\epsilon^2<\epsilon$. Letting $x = \epsilon^2$, we have $x<\delta=\epsilon$ but $\sqrt{x} = \epsilon\not<\epsilon$. So you can't use $\delta=\epsilon$ if you want to show continuity, since it breaks for small $\epsilon$.

As you know a correct proof is given by chosing $\delta=\epsilon^2$.

Comment: @mathguruu, if ${x}\leq 1$, then $|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}|$ is smaller or equal than what fixed real positive number?

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof I think 1? So if $|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|=|\sqrt{x}| \leq 1$ if $x \leq  1$

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1855106)

Comment: @user264745 I do think that this answers their question, they understood that their proof didn't work and in their edit asked if their reasoning for it not working was correct, i.e. if it was correct that $|\frac{\delta}{\sqrt{x}}|<\delta$ is not always true. Which was what I answered. I am new to stackexchange, is it standard to put short answers like these in a comment?

Comment: @user264745 I have edited my question to give a more detailed answer to the poster.

Answer (score 0):

If $0<\sqrt{x}<\epsilon$ then $x<\epsilon^2$. Therefore, we MUST choose $\delta$ so that $\delta\leq\epsilon^2$. Right? Because of the definition of the limit.

But, if $\epsilon<1$ then $\epsilon^2<\epsilon$, so we can not choose $\delta=\epsilon$ since then $\delta>\epsilon^2$.